# Appending a unique identifier to bash commands

Tags: bash

I'm running a command, and I'd like to be able to use `pkill -f` to kill that specific command instance later. There's no reasonable way for me to get the PID.

So, my idea was instead to append a unique identifier to the end of the command, as such:

```
./command argument1 argument2 UNIQUE-IDENTIFIER-ASDF-GHJK-123
```

Then later if I want to kill it, I could just do

```
pkill -f UNIQUE-IDENTIFIER-ASDF-GHJK-123
```

Thing is, `./command` is strict in only taking two arguments so by passing the third unique identifier, it'll error.

Is there a way to include this unique identifier string in somehow, without passing it to `./command`?

Thanks.

Comment: Which OS/distribution and version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Linux:

Prefix your command with a variable with a unique value

```
IDENTIFIER=ASDF ./command argument1 argument2
```

Later search this variable to get the PID and kill the process

```
grep -sa IDENTIFIER=ASDF /proc/*/environ | cut -d '/' -f 3 | xargs kill
```